# Python: subtract lists in a list while iteration

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

my multidimensional list looks like:

```
A = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12], [13,14,15], [16,17,18]]
```

I want to get the difference between the elements of the sublists as one list, like:

`B= [ [1-4, 2-5, 3-6], [4-7, 5-8, 6-9], [7-10, 8-11,9-12] [10-13, 11-14, 12-15] ]`

and so on.

How can I get this? Thank you for any suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`operator.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.sub):

```
>>> from operator import sub
>>> A = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12], [13,14,15], [16,17,18]]
>>> [map(sub, a, b) for a, b in zip(A, A[1:])]
[[-3, -3, -3], [-3, -3, -3], [-3, -3, -3], [-3, -3, -3], [-3, -3, -3]]
```

Comment: that´s great. you helped a python beginner so much ;)

Comment: if i have more of lists like A and i want to iterate over all of them, How can I modify your code? with a for loop?

Comment: @lara May be something like: `[[map(sub, a, b) a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:])] for lst in lists]`

Comment: i tried this with a for loop: `for i in range(len(lists)): lst=lists[i]`  `[[map(sub, a, b) a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:])]` and that works! thank you!

Comment: @lara Great! Don't use `range(len(lists))` though, in Python you can simply iterate over a list: `for lst in lists: print [[map(sub, a, b) a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:])]`